# Cocoa Swift: How to add "Application Scene" to StoryBoard

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode-storyboard, xcode10.2

I'm trying to implement a StoryBoard in Document-Base application but I can figure out how to add "Application Scene":

[image]

when I search in the object library the only two options I got are the following:

[image]

[image]

Any of you knows how or why the object library is now showing "Application Scene" ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want to add a second application to your application project?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I'm trying to add a second application